# Is there a function to remove the 'disabled' attribute of a select-option menu when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I currently have an 'edit' button and some jquery script on my site which can be used to remove the 'readonly' attributes from the inputs and textareas when necessary.

However... I also have a select few select menus with a 'disabled' attribute, which I also need to be 'enabled' (for editing) when the same edit button is clicked.

Below is the edit button and code I have been using to remove just the 'readonly' attributes.

BUTTON:

```
<button id="removeAttribute" class="editButton" name="editButton" onclick="style.display = 'none'"></button>
```

FIELDS:

```
<input type="text"  id="customerName" class="customer_name" name="customer_name" value="<?php echo                        $_POST['customer_name']; ?>" readonly>


<select class="flavor_menu" name="flavor_menu" disabled>   
     <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
     <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
     <option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>     
</select>
```

EDIT CODE:

```
const button = document.querySelector("#removeAttribute");
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute("readonly");
    });

});
```

My failed attempt to 'enable' the 'flavor_menu', select-option menu with the same 'editButton':

```
const button = document.querySelector("#removeAttribute");
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute("readonly, disabled");
    });

});
```

Comment: `removeAttribute("disabled")`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Yes, I have tried that too. It did not work. :( 

element.removeAttribute("readonly", "disabled");

Comment: `element.removeAttribute("readonly", "disabled");` is not what I suggested?